# Loop through all files in a specific folder and insert filename into Excel at a specific cell

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have a formatte Excel worsheet that I want to use as an invoice.  I want to be able to loop through all the files in a specific folder and add the file name, at a specific cell and inserting new rows below.

I currently have the below but i cant find any good examples that would allow me to add new content at a very specific range and then continue to add new content below that while maintaining the Excel file's formatting.

```
            string path = @"C:\MyWorkingFolder";
            string rootfolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            string folder = Path.GetFileName(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));

            var xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            var xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, ReadOnly: true);
            Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets["Invoice"];

            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(rootfolder);

            int count = d.GetFiles("*.doc*").Length;

            Console.WriteLine("Found {0} files.", count);
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(rootfolder, "*.doc*"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Processing...");

                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                WriteFileNameToExcel(xlWorkSheet, FileName);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.Write("Press any key to End.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            // Disable file override confirmaton message  
            xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;


            string newfile = string.Format(rootfolder + @"\" + "H&K Invoice - {0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy"));
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs(newfile, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
            xlWorkBook.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);


    private static void WriteFileNameToExcel(Worksheet ws, string filename)
    {
      //How to target the specific cell, then insert new rows so as to maintain formatting

    }
```

Comment: I've updated my original question to be more specific. I merely want to be able to add an unknown number of rows into the excel SS, starting at row x and inserting down.

Answer (score 0):

Insert Row keeping the formatting above:

```
Rows("8:8").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Adding content to that new row without changing the formatting:

```
Cells(8,1).value = "This is new"
```

Spice up with variables to get the current last row and add your new row below that.